# Write SearchCursor records into a table in reportlab

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, reportlab

I started to use ArcGIS Pro 2.0 recently. There is no reporting yet and I am using reportlab to create my pdfs (.rlf does not exist in ArcGIS pro). I also use platypus to create tables. The forums are very active so this part was okay.

I am working with parcels. I have to export the attribute tables records, after making a selection of the new parcels created or updated (landsurveyors need to review them). I am using arcpy.searchCursor to open and read my table. I can print the results after sorting them. However I would like to write the results in a table format Inside my pdf template.

I found this: [Using ArcPy and Python to export Table View as PDF format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98135/using-arcpy-and-python-to-export-table-view-as-pdf-format), which is close to what I want. However this is for ArcMap and does not seem to work with ArcGIS pro.

Any ideas?

Comment: I used to do PDF maps with reports using ReportLab and ArcPy with ArcMap. Now I create my reports using ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro alone using some new coding patterns that I am close to completing an eLearning video course about that I'll publish on Udemy.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I am sure that would definitely be helpful for a lot of people.

Comment: I released that course, titled [Challenging Times with Python and ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro](https://www.udemy.com/challenging-times-with-python-and-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro) a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem using `reportlab` to export the data in a feature class into a table inside a .pdf using ArcGIS Pro.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, portrait
from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\USA\Cities'
data = [(f[0], f[1], f[2]) for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['STATE_NAME', 'CITY_NAME', 'POP1990'],
                                                         where_clause="STATE_NAME = 'Hawaii'")]

#or dummy #data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
#data
#[('Hawaii', 'Wahiawa', 17386), ('Hawaii', 'Schofield Barracks', 19597),...]
cnvs = canvas.Canvas(r'C:\GIS\report.pdf',pagesize=portrait(A4))

table = Table(data, colWidths=140, rowHeights=20)

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(3,0),colors.lightgrey)]))

#draw the table
table.wrapOn(cnvs,200,400)
table.drawOn(cnvs,10,200)

#draw and save
cnvs.showPage()
cnvs.save()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. From the code you shared I understand what was missing in my tests. However, trying your code I get an error with wrapOn and drawOn: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'wrapOn'.

Comment: Nevermind solved it! Thank you I managed to get my table. Need to work on the pretty side of the table now but got what I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Np, great it worked. Styling is always the hardest part ;)